# UISwitch action not work in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, uiswitch

I have a switch button in one cell of table view. Previously in iOS 9, everything works fine, after click switch button will goto the action method.But after update to iOS 10, the action method never be called. Anyone has similar issue like this?

cell.m

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        // Initialization code

        UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [bgView setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"customcell.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)]];
        [self setBackgroundView:bgView];


        UIImageView *selectedBgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [selectedBgView setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellselect.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)]];

        [self setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBgView];

        nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 13, 250, 40)];

        [nameLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];

        [nameLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
        [nameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [nameLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

        [self.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];

        switchButton = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(230, 17, 100, 30)];

        [switchButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];

        [switchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(switchActivated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [switchButton setHidden:YES];

        [self.contentView addSubview:switchButton];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Action method:

```
- (void) switchActivated:(id)sender
{
    if(switchButton.on)
    {
        [selectedItem setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"valueEntry"];
    }
    else 
    {
        [selectedItem setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"valueEntry"];
    }
}
```

ViewController.m 
cell for row at index path:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"homeReportCustomizationCell_%d",indexPath.row]];

        if(!tableViewCell)
        {
            tableViewCell = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell_%d",indexPath.row]];
        }
...........
}
```

Comment: remove this ` [switchButton setHidden:YES];` and check

Comment: That's not the issue, I have other method to control show or hide of this button, now I can click the button but it's not goto the action method

Comment: What is self.contentView ? It should be cell.contentView. Check it please.

Comment: @DavidKong So your `switchActivated` method is not even getting called or   what? Give a try adding NSLog there in method or breakpoint. Because I think method should get a call. Also try changing the control event to - `UIControlEventValueChanged`

Comment: I found the issue, this project using ios6.1 as base SDK and deployment target is 6.1, after I change all to 7.0 everything works fine again...don't know why, coz previously works fine for all devices under 10.0, after update to iOS 10 got this weird issue. This project is too old and need do something to improve this. Thanks for all your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`  inside     `[switchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(switchActivated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

To: `UIControlEventValueChanged`

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue!

I have a UISwitch and a UITextField inside a UIScrollView.
I add the scrollView to my self.view.

I tested this with an iPad Pro running iOS 10--
Before upgrading to the latest version of iOS, everything worked just fine.
Now my methods are not getting called!!

Hopefully I won't have to resort to a programmatic solution-- that would be a bummer.